# Why GetValidationResult disable lazy loading prior to executing the validations?

Tags: entity-framework

Why GetValidationResult method of Entity Framework will disable lazy loading prior to executing the validations.

Which are adverse effects of lazy loading during validation?

Answer (score 0):

To not to load entities that were not loaded before validation started. First validation is just for validating and not loading entities. Second, you don't want extra queries being sent to the database when validating. Third (related to second) - extra queries would kill performance of validation - a single query may take longer than the validation itself and there is a risk of sending tons of these. Btw. what is the scenario where you would want lazy loading being enabled during validation?